# Earning the Enlightened Badge

Tags: support, badges

The englightened badge read "First answer was accepted with at least 10 up votes". What does this mean exactly? *My* first answer (ever)? The first answer for any particular question (chronologically)? If it gets accepted before it has 10 upvotes does it not get awarded?

I ask because I have the Guru badge ("Accepted answer and voted up 40 times") which only 6 other people have - but not the Enlightened badge, which 199 people have. I only have 1 answer that is accepted and has more than 10 upvotes. ([See here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/567/how-can-i-chop-onions-without-crying/570#570) if you care.)

I'm not asking this as a means of complaining, more a general interest in how this works. My startup actually helps other companies incorporate points/badges into their sites so it's also a bit of personal interest for me. It's possible that it is also a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the first answer on a question, as the description states.

Comment: Well I asked because it wasn't entirely clear if the description meant "on a question" or some other qualifier. Thanks for the clarification though.